# Pandas select rows and get highest column value based on another column

Tags: pandas

I have data set that I want to get the highest score based on the 'topic' within each 'path'. Basically, I am trying to get high score received for the students.

```
l1 = ['/some/path/A','/some/path/A','/some/path/A','/some/path/2','/some/path/2']
l2 = ['paper1','paper1','paper1','paper2','paper2']
l3 = ['Tree','Tree','Axe','Leaf','Leaf']
l4 = [.68,.90,.80,.65,.30]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'path': l1,
     'paper_name': l2,
     'topic': l3,
     'score':l4
    })
df
```

## current df

```
path            paper_name      topic   score
/some/path/A    paper1          Tree    0.68
/some/path/A    paper1          Tree    0.90
/some/path/A    paper1          Axe     0.80
/some/path/2    paper2          Leaf    0.65
/some/path/2    paper2          Leaf    0.30
```

I have tried this logic:

```
df[df['topic']=='Tree' & df['score'].max()] # hard coding. need something more simpler not hard coded like the way I am doing it. It also errors out because of data types. How do get this?
```

## output needed:

```
path            paper_name      topic   score
/some/path/A    paper1          Tree    0.90
/some/path/A    paper1          Axe     0.80
/some/path/2    paper2          Leaf    0.65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `sort` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df_final = df.sort_values('score').drop_duplicates('topic', keep='last').sort_index()

Out[76]:
  paper_name          path  score topic
1     paper1  /some/path/A   0.90  Tree
2     paper1  /some/path/A   0.80   Axe
3     paper2  /some/path/2   0.65  Leaf
```

Or `groupby.idxmax` and slicing

```
df_final = df.loc[df.groupby('topic', sort=False).score.idxmax()]

Out[82]:
  paper_name          path  score topic
1     paper1  /some/path/A   0.90  Tree
2     paper1  /some/path/A   0.80   Axe
3     paper2  /some/path/2   0.65  Leaf
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about sort_value. I chose to got with one that has `idmax()`